# set operator minus not showing results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count SECTION_ID AS SECTIONS and ENROLL_DATE AS STUDENTS here, I am getting the right result from students column, but not from sections column. I want only SECTION_ID from SECTION table and not from ENROLLMENT table, so I did minus set operation. Why is it giving me results from the both tables ? How could I only get results from SECTION table ?

```
 SELECT s.LOCATION,COUNT(s.SECTION_ID) AS SECTIONS, COUNT(e.ENROLL_DATE) AS STUDENTS
 FROM SECTION s
 JOIN ENROLLMENT e
 ON s.SECTION_ID = e.SECTION_ID
 WHERE EXISTS (

           SELECT SECTION_ID
           FROM SECTION
            MINUS
           SELECT SECTION_ID
           FROM ENROLLMENT

            )
 AND s.SECTION_ID = e.SECTION_ID
 GROUP BY s.LOCATION
 ORDER BY s.LOCATION;
```

I am getting this result

```
 LOCATION  SECTIONS   STUDENTS
 ---------- ---------- ----------
   H310        1        1
   L206        8        8
   L210        29       29
   L211        10       10
   L214        36       36
   etc
```

result I want

```
 LOCATION  SECTIONS   STUDENTS
 ---------- ---------- ----------
   H310        1        1
   L206        1        8
   L210        10       29
   L211        3        10
   L214        15       36
   etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without the example data that produces these results, but I think you might be wanting count distinct:

```
Select
    s.location,
    count(distinct s.section_id) as sections,
    count(e.enroll_date) as students
from
   section s
       inner join
   enrollment e
       on s.section_id = e.section_id
group by
    s.location
order by
    s.location;
```

Your exists criteria is probably not doing what you expect as there's no correlation between the inner and outer part. You've also repeated `s.section_id = e.section_id` in the join and the where clause.

Comment: you got the result right...so I basically did not even need minus set operation. I like your style, this is gonna help me do other stuff that I need...thanks!

Comment: Yep - `count(*)` counts all rows in the result set, `count(column)` counts the number of rows with non-null column, and `count(distinct column)` counts the number of different non-null values in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is that you want the distinct keyword...

Like this:

```
 SELECT s.LOCATION,
        COUNT(DISTINCT s.SECTION_ID) AS SECTIONS, 
        COUNT(e.ENROLL_DATE) AS STUDENTS
 FROM SECTION s
 JOIN ENROLLMENT e
 ON s.SECTION_ID = e.SECTION_ID
 WHERE EXISTS (    
           SELECT SECTION_ID
           FROM SECTION
            MINUS
           SELECT SECTION_ID
           FROM ENROLLMENT    
            )
 AND s.SECTION_ID = e.SECTION_ID
 GROUP BY s.LOCATION
 ORDER BY s.LOCATION;
```

Comment: so basically I had duplicates hmmm

Comment: @Dana, you were counting the same session multiple times. For instance if students 1, 2 and 3 were signed up for section 1: you'd have 3 records(student, section | 1,1 | 2,1 | 3,1) which works when you're counting students, but it was the same section counted multiple times.